# Pull the PR coming from a forked repo for testing in local

Tags: git, bitbucket

In our team half uses branching on the original repo and some fork the repositories into their own. We now have a PR from the forked repo going to master, how can I pull the changes of that particular PR to my local so I can check on my local the effect of his changes?

Comment: I think what you answered is what I am looking for

Answer (score 4):

Create a new origin pointing to the forked repo:

```
git remote add fork1 git@github.com:someuser/somerepo.git
git fetch fork1
git checkout fork1/somebranch # checkout the code in the fork
```